# Utilizando return de outra classe

Tags: java

Bom dia amigos, Estou tentando implementar esse código mas está dando erro.

```
 public int totalFaltasAluno(int matricula) {
        int totalFaltas = 0;
        for(Integer item : faltas){
            if(item == matricula){
                totalFaltas++;
            } 
        }
        return   totalFaltas;

 public boolean verificarReprovacaoPorFalta(int matricula) {
    int presenca = 90 - totalFaltas;//90 são os dias de aulas
    if (presenca  < (90-0.75-90));// presenca menor que 75% de 90 dias de aulas
         return true;
}
```

erro:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation 
    problem: 
    totalFaltas cannot be resolved to a variable

at Gerenciar_frequencia.Pauta.verificarReprovacaoPorFalta(Pauta.java:45)
```

Classe main está assim.

```
 if (pauta.verificarReprovacaoPorFalta(aluno.getMatricula())){
            System.out.println(" Presença: reprovado");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(" Presença: normal");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa chamar o método para fazer o uso do mesmo. Deixo abaixo um exemplo comentado:

```
 public int totalFaltasAluno(int matricula) {
        int totalFaltas = 0;
        for(Integer item : faltas){
            if(item == matricula){
                totalFaltas++;
            } 
        }
        return   totalFaltas;
 }
 public boolean verificarReprovacaoPorFalta(int matricula) {
    // aplicando regra de 3 para saber o percentual dessa quantidade de faltas
    double percentualDePresenca = ((90 - totalFaltasAluno(matricula)) * 100) / 90;

    // comparando o percentual para ver se é menor que 75% de 90 dias.
    return (percentualDePresenca < 75);
 }
```

> Não entendi muito bem a sua lógica para o método `totalFaltasAluno` mas para resolver o problema mencionado, basta que você chame o método ao invés da variável pois a mesma não existe na definição da classe apenas localmente no método.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, acrescentei uma parte da classe main, não consegui implementar , o retorno é sempre fica  "true".

Comment: para ficar sempre true a presença está sendo menor que (90-0.75-90) = -0.75..

Comment: Editei o algoritmo, se vc quer 75% de 90 é só mutiplicar 90 por 0.75 e não subtrair. Para saber quantos % a quantidade X de faltas representa em 90 é necessário fazer uso da regra de 3. Editei o algoritmo.

Comment: hiago Souza, está retornando true sempre, mas obrigado.

Comment: Que valor tem no totalFaltas?

Comment: Agora que notei o nome do método atualizei as rotinas..

Comment: Tenho 3 totais de faltas , são 27, 6, 0

Comment: Tente novamente, editei o script... Eu me confundi aqui

Comment: obrigado mais uma vez Hiago, mas está retornando true novamente.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93259/discussion-between-bruno-and-hiago-souza).